# What does exclusion constraint `EXCLUDE USING gist (c WITH &&)` mean?

Tags: postgresql, exclusion-constraint

From PostgreSQL document

> Exclusion constraints ensure that if any two rows are compared on the
>   specified columns or expressions using the specified operators, at
>   least one of these operator comparisons will return false or null. The
>   syntax is:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE circles (
>     c circle,
>     EXCLUDE USING gist (c WITH &&)
> );
> ```

I was wondering what `EXCLUDE USING gist (c WITH &&)` means? In particular, `gist()`, `c WITH &&` and `EXCLUDE USING`.

Can it be rewritten in terms of `check`? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/pgconf/not-just-unique-exclusion-constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I love the example of excluding on `<>` to ensure that all rows match.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Whereas a `CHECK` constraint evaluates an expression based on a single row of the table, an `EXCLUDE` constraint evaluates a comparison of two rows in the table. Think of it like a generalised `UNIQUE` constraint: instead of "no two rows can be equal", you can say things like "no two rows overlap", or even "no two rows can be *different*".

In order to achieve this without checking every possible combination of values, it needs an appropriate index structure which allows it to find possible violations when you insert or update a row. This is what the `gist` part of the declaration refers to: [a particular type of index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html) which can be used to speed up operations other than equality.

The remainder of the declaration is the constraint itself: `c` is the column being tested, and `&&` is the operator which must not return true for any pair of rows. In this case, `&&` is the "overlaps" operator [as listed on the geometric operators manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html).

So put together, the constraint `EXCLUDE USING gist (c WITH &&)` translates to "no two values of `c` must overlap each other (more precisely, `A.c && B.c` must return false or null for all distinct rows `A` and `B`), and please use a `gist` index to monitor this constraint".

Comment: Appreciate if you could add scenarios where it makes most sense to use

Comment: Found a gist showing an example with rooms in a hotel which may not booked in the same time frame: https://gist.github.com/fphilipe/0a2a3d50a9f3834683bf

Comment: @MaulikModi See at the end for another hotel room example here: https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/postgres-constraints-for-newbies

Comment: @IMSoP how do you make a constraint that ensures "no two rows can be different"? ie. I want to exclude tsrange overlaps only when the user is different...

Comment: @Zaffer That sounds like a new question, rather than anything directly related to this answer, so should be posted on its own page. There is an example in the slides linked by a_horse_with_no_name which might be what you're looking for though.

Comment: @IMSoP I made a question that is more fleshed out and also maybe there is a better way to do it then using something with NOT EQUAL... https://stackoverflow.com/q/72207993/14305096