# Postgres exclude constraint for overlapping timestamp ranges only where another column's row is NOT EQUAL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

In Postgres I have a table of events on seats that records both reservations AND occupancies based on event type. I want to add a third constraint that prevents one user from making a reservation and another user from occupying at the same time.

So far I have this with two constraints for no same events overlapping per seat and no same events overlapping on different seats by the same user:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.seat_event
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer references users(id) NOT NULL,
    seat_id integer references area_seat(id) NOT NULL,
    timestamp_range tstzrange,
    event_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    canceled boolean DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT seat_event_overlap EXCLUDE USING gist (
        seat_id WITH =,
        event_type WITH =,
        timestamp_range WITH &&)
        WHERE (not canceled),
    CONSTRAINT event_user_one_seat EXCLUDE USING gist (
        user_id WITH =,
        event_type WITH =,
        timestamp_range WITH &&)
        WHERE (not canceled),
    CONSTRAINT seat_event_one_user EXCLUDE USING gist (
        seat_id WITH =,
        user_id WITH =, -- TODO must be where user is not equal
        timestamp_range WITH &&)
        WHERE (not canceled)
);
```

How do I make this third constraint work where the exclusion must apply when the user_id is NOT THE SAME?

Or perhaps there is a more elegant why to think of these constraints?