# Logical operators in a Postgres EXCLUDE constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, exclusion-constraint

Consider a following schema with a date range that must not overlap between two arbitrary rows:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
     duration tsrange,
     active   bool,
     EXCLUDE USING gist (duration WITH &&)
);
```

How would I limit this constraint to rows where `active` is true?
Meaning that no two rows with both `active` = true can overlap in date. Rows with `active` = false would be allowed to overlap with any other row.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247705/7531353), the above exclude constraint checks that for every two rows `A.duration && B.duration` is false or null. The conclusion would be to use a logical operator to check if both `active`s are true.

**What I tried** is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
     duration tsrange,
     active   bool,
     EXCLUDE USING gist (duration WITH &&, active WITH AND)
);
```

But this operator does not seem to be supported by the exclude syntax:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AND"
```

The bit-wise and `&` does also not work:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
     duration tsrange,
     active   bool,
     EXCLUDE USING gist (duration WITH &&, active WITH &)
);
ERROR:  data type boolean has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Is there any possibility to express my constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want to allow or disallow.

If you want to allow overlap as long as at most one member of each overlap is 'active', then you need a simple EXCLUDE with a WHERE clause, not a compounded EXCLUDE.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
     duration tsrange,
     active   bool,
     EXCLUDE USING gist (duration WITH &&) where (active is true)
);
```

Comment: I want to check for overlap where both rows are 'active'. I have edited my post to hopefully be more clear about it.

Comment: @HeapUnderflow I think we are describing the same thing, so my answer should work for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason, I was under the assumption I would not be able to insert active rows where an inactive is. This was wrong.

Comment: How about the cases when you want at least one of the records to be `active` for a unique column `duration`?  Would it be possible to achieve it with `EXCLUDE USING gist`?

Comment: @Victoria  Not really sure what you are asking.  If the column is declared unique, there can only be one record for it at all.  Maybe ask a new question and include a more complete example.